# Breakpoints not hitting in Chrome v33.0.1750.154

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, script-debugging

I am using the Chrome v33.0.1750.154, and I am not able to debug javascript in the debugger/scripts windows; although I am able to set/enable/disable breakpoints. This happens only for JS file on our company servers, and works fine if I try a sample JS locally on my machine. Actually debugging was working fine until this afternoon. Not sure what changed!

Anybody face the same problem? and have a solution? Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

Comment: Oh BTW I am not able to debug the script, otherwise he page/script works fine. Also the weird thing I noticed is I am able to hit the break point set at the top of the file where my constants are declared [before the jquery onload $(function() {...});]. But breakpoints places elsewhere are not hit at all!

Answer (score 0):

i had that problem but after doing reinstall of chrome and reboot it was all ok again. Maybe with only re-boot of pc will be solved. I tried to delete cookies cache etc but only this solved my problem.

Comment: I did not reinstall but have tried clearing cookies for my site, restarting Chrome, rebooting machine etc. Has not worked yet!

Comment: I have tried reinstalling Chrome. No luck yet. I am not sure what is wrong with Chrome. Is there something, setting or something, that is preventing debugging for my site?